# Setting application icon in Explorer?

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I am trying to set a file icon for a program I am creating. I can get the icon to show on the `taskBar` when I am running the program. But I can't get it to show in a file explorer.

Here is an example screenshot from Explorer:

[image: Example]

I have embedded the icon into the project, and set it as the windows icon using

```
Icon="Sample.ico"
```

Thanks

Comment: try compiling your code in "Release" mode.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Have you selected the icon for your application? (project properties > tab application > symbol and manifest > symbol)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that this was a part of visual studio.

Answer (score 12):

The following example shows how to set a window icon.

By using XAML,

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  x:Class="SDKSample.MainWindow"
    Icon="WPFIcon1.ico">
</Window>
```

By using c# code,

```
Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFIcon2.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

By using VB,

```
Dim iconUri As New Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFIcon2.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
Me.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri)
```

For more info, [refer this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. OP is not asking about the corner icon for the window.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your .ico file contains the right selection of sizes so that the appropriate one displays in explorer.

For Windows you'll want:
256 x 256 pixels, 
48 x 48 pixels, 
32 x 32 pixels and 
16 x 16 pixels.

All 32bit (24bit colour, 8bit transparency).

Answer (score -1):

Kindly use the .ico file don't use JPEG or any other formats

```
<Window Icon="youricon.ico"></Window>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx

Answer (score -1):

you have to include  `Icon="Path to icon"` in window definition of the main window.

```
<Window 
//rest of code
Icon="Path to icon"></Window>
```